# PHPMailer: include(/var/www/sendingmail/protected/extensions/phpmailer/JPhpMailer.php) failed to open stream No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send mails in Yii.

I have downloaded the extension from [Github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and included them in `/protected/extensions`

I have also imported it in `main.php`.

But when I try to send mail, it gives me an error

> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

My controller:

```
public function actionContact()
{
    $model=new ContactForm;
    if(isset($_POST['ContactForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['ContactForm'];

        if($model->validate())
        {
            Yii::import('application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer');
            $mail = new JPhpMailer;
            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = true;
            $mail->Username = 'from@gmail.com';
            $mail->Port = '465';
            $mail->Password = 'password';
            $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
            $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
            $mail->SetFrom('from@gmail.com', 'myname');
            $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via GMail, basic with authentication';
            $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';
            $mail->MsgHTML('<h1>JUST A TEST!</h1>');
            $mail->AddAddress('to@gmail.com', 'John Doe'); $mail->Send();
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('contact','Thank you for... as possible.');
            $this->refresh();
        }
    }
    $this->render('contact',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

There is an error with this line:

```
$mail = new JPhpMailer;
```

Comment: which file cannot be found?

Comment: include(/var/www/sendingmail/protected/extensions/phpmailer/JPhpMailer.php)

Comment: Okay, apart from missing single quote, does the file exist in the path (and does the web server have read permission)?

Comment: Call me crazy but is it really meant to have a *"J"* prefix? Also, you should add the error message **in full** to your question.

Comment: Yes reading permissions are there, where is the missing single quote? I'm sry I could'nt find it

Comment: @Phil even if I remove the "J" prefix, its giving me the same error as "failed to open(PHPMailer)"

Comment: file is not properly imported using import. You have to check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it by myself,

I have included this line in my controller -:-
require("class.phpmailer.php");

Its working now

Answer (score 0):

> Your phpmailer file should be included in the folder phpmailer
>   which contains extensions as main folder and it contains applications as main folder
>
> phpmailer folder should have the file phpmailer.php
>
> applications->extensions->phpmailer->phpmailer.php is the correct path

Comment: Yes its included in the same way

Comment: you mentioned above that you have included in /protected/extensions

Comment: I mentioned that I have included the whole folder(that I have downloaded from given link) in /protected/extensions

Comment: Sorry I can't get you...if the downloaded folder name is phpmailer then it is in extensions folder which is in applications folder. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes. When I have downloaded it from the given link, it came with a default name PHPMAILER-MASTER which is included as protected/extensions/phpmailer-master/class.phpmailer.php

Comment: application.extensions.phpmailer.JPhpMailer  is the import path that you have mentioned. As per the above comment, then it can be protected.extensions.phpmailer-master.JPhpMailer. I'm not sure but this is just my suggestion. If you are interested, please test this

Comment: Yes I have tried it,it says "Make sure it points to an existing directory or file. "